# Can H1 be in a Title element?

Tags: html, seo

For a better SEO, can I do something like that:

```html
<title><h1>My title !</h1></title>
```

or I should delete the h1 element ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no, delete them.

The title tag does not support any internal tags. It is meant to be plain text and should be placed inside the head tag. Any tags inside it will be ignored/stripped out.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title

Heading tags are semantic tags that should be used inside the body of the HTML.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements

Comment: what about reverse ? title inside h1 ?

Comment: Also not valid HTML

Answer (score 1):

No, you must delete H1 tag because you can't place anything in the title tag